# want to display data using indexing..?

Tags: php, javascript, html

i am working on codeigniter. I want to display data from backend to the view files. here is my code

```
$result = $obj->get_details();

if ($result[0])
     {
           for ($i=0; $i<count($result); $i++) {

               echo $result [$i]['name'];
           }
     }
```

while i am doing so i am getting error "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array". I want to display the data using indexing. for example i just want to display the name on the 5th index of an array. Any help would be awesome... THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($result); $i++) {

    echo $result[$i]->name;
}
```

Because `$result[$i]` is an object that will contains the `name` value

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo $result [$i]->name;
```

instead of

```
echo $result [$i]['name'];
```